# How to run Python".exe" not Spawned, as it is by >python "myscript.py"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After creating the ".exe" from "myscript.py" by the command line:

> pyinstaller --onefile -w myscript.py

i see that windows 10 spawn the process, it does not wait for the execution as it usually do if i execute as original script by the command line:

> python myscript.py

So, how to run the ".exe" as it runed by python ???? Not spawing it.

Also no "print()" prints anything what i guess that it is because the main output port has been changed by the spawning stuff...

##### myscript.py

```
import sys


def main():
    print('Hello World!') 
    sys.stdout.flush()


main()
```

Comment: How can you even tell it's not waiting?  That program should complete in about a microsecond.

Comment: @MarkRansom What they are referring to is that a program that has its subsystem set to "GUI" in its PE header will not get the parent console I/O inherited and cmd and powershell also won't wait for its execution to finish unlike they do for programs with the subsystem set to "Console".

Comment: @CherryDT I'm glad you can make some sense of this question, because I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifically asked for this behavior through [`-w` (`--windowed`)](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.1/usage.html#cmdoption-w):

> Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o.

Don't use `-w` if you want a CLI program (and you are using the console). Use `-w` if you want a GUI program (and you are showing your own dialog windows and such).